# Marketing Cloud Triggered send - error '10004'

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I have created a Triggered send definition under trigger sends linked with static email and also linked a data extension based on triggered send template.

```
    [
            {
    "From": {
        "Address": "no-reply@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "No reply"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "exacttarget@gmail.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "exacttarget@gmail.com"


},
    "Options": {
        "RequestType": "SYNC"
    }
  }            ]
```

Am hitting the below end point for triggered send:
https://host.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:externalkey/send

Am getting an error like

```
{
"message": "Problem initating message send during deserialization of JSON payload.",
"errorcode": 10004,
"documentation": ""
}
```

Please help

Comment: 10004 means that there is the following error: `Invalid Message Format - Serialization error, please ensure the body has balanced braces and brackets`. (ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm) This means that likely your JSON is malformed. I would put it through a linter (https://jsonlint.com/) to find the error.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington....Thanks for your reply....It says its a valid JSON.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't be in an array, and I would also check on if your email requires any personalization as if so, you will need to include that information in the 'ContactAttributes' section under 'To'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it in an array.

Try without []

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "no-reply@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "No reply"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "exacttarget@gmail.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "exacttarget@gmail.com"
    },
    "Options": {
        "RequestType": "SYNC"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike Its working now. That Array is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
{
"From": {
    "Address": "no-reply@exacttarget.com",
    "Name": "No reply"
},
"To": {
    "Address": "exacttarget@gmail.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "exacttarget@gmail.com",
    "ContactAttributes": {
        "SubscriberAttributes": {
            "Name": "test"
        }
    }
} 
}
```